# PutAsync() method call failing in Blazor WebAssembly project, yet debugging not working well enough to see what's going on

Tags: http, data-binding, blazor, webassembly, visual-studio-debugging

I've been trying to learn Blazor WebAssembly programming and have been doing a follow-along project along with the Pluralsight course I'm working on.

What happens is that the PutAsync() method in the following code fails:

```
        public async Task UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            try
            {
                var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(employee).ToString();
                var employeeJson =
                    new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(employee), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                await _httpClient.PutAsync($"/api/employee", employeeJson);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

This code is located in a service class, and the target method that has the HttpPut attribute either doesn't seem to get called, or the breakpoint I place in it never gets hit.

```
  [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult UpdateEmployee([FromBody] Employee employee)
        {
            if (employee == null)
                return BadRequest();

            if (employee.FirstName == string.Empty || employee.LastName == string.Empty)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Name/FirstName", "The name or first name shouldn't be empty");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var employeeToUpdate = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeById(employee.EmployeeId);

            if (employeeToUpdate == null)
                return NotFound();

            _employeeRepository.UpdateEmployee(employee);

            return NoContent(); //success
        }
```

I put the breakpoint on the `if (employee == null)` line, but it doesn't get hit. I initially had a lot of problems with breakpoints not being hit, but ever since I switched from Firefox to Chrome for my testing, it's been a lot better. Yet, the execution doesn't seem to get here. The routing attributes at the top of this target class looks like the following:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
```

The class itself is called `EmployeeController`, so I would think that the `"api/employee"` attribute should reach it.

I've added a try/catch block around the failing code in the first code block I've posted, and when I step through, I see that there's an exception that gets thrown after I try to step over the PutAsync() method. But when I go to command window to se what the content of ex.Message is, I get the "Unable to Evaluate" error in Visual Studio.

[image]

If I step through, I see the execution hitting some bound fields in the Razor file that displays the edit form, but I don't know enough about Razor to really deduce what is going on. There are numerous fields in there that look like this:

```
   <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-3">Last name: </label>
            <InputText id="lastName" @bind-Value="@Employee.LastName" class="form-control col-sm-8" placeholder="Enter last name"></InputText>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3">First name: </label>
            <InputText id="firstName" class="form-control col-sm-8" @bind-Value="@Employee.FirstName" placeholder="Enter first name"></InputText>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="birthdate" class="col-sm-3">Birthdate: </label>
            <InputDate id="birthdate" class="form-control col-sm-8" @bind-Value="@Employee.BirthDate" placeholder="Enter birthdate"></InputDate>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-3">Email: </label>
            <InputText id="email" class="form-control col-sm-8" @bind-Value="@Employee.Email" placeholder="Enter email"></InputText>
        </div>
```

And then, at some point, while stepping through, a lot of the fields get skipped, and the execution seems to leave the Razor file abruptly. I am not sure what to make of this, and since I have been largely absent from .Net for the last several years, it all does feel a bit overwhelming. I am not quite sure how the PutAsync() method call failure really translates into these possible data binding errors, but I am guessing that PutAsync() is just a vehicle to call whatever code has the [HttpPut] attribute, and that any kind of exception anywhere down the line from this method call will cause the PutAsync() call to fail. Would that be accurate or not?

Comment: You need to know that error, replace System.Diagnostics.Debug. with Console.  (output shows up in the Browser Dev Tools comsole).

Comment: the endpoint you are trying to hit, whats the response when you try to access it from brower manually?

Comment: also can you add `[Route("[action]")]` underneath `[HttpPut]` and see if it works

Comment: Thank you for the Browser Dev Tools tip. I didn't know about that one and kept wondering where the console output would have been going. Well, I changed the code and got this:
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44340/api/employee' from origin 'https://localhost:44362' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response. 
I added the AllowAnyMethods() call to the CORS policy in the startup.cs of the web service, and everything works. I know this isn't a sound programming practice, but I can at least keep going with the course.

Answer (score 1):

try to await "api/employee"

```
var employeeToUpdate = await _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeById(employee.EmployeeId);
```

Comment: The EndPoint and the Repository look like they are not-async.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use Built-in form components without `EditForm` and `model` or `EditContext`.
2. Use `DataAnnotationsValidator` and/or `ValidationSummary` component to validate your form before submitting.
3. use `OnValidSubmit` method to submit your form only when has a validate controls.
4. If you don't want to use `OnValidSubmit`, check if your `EditContext` validate before request `PutAsync()`.
5. Please check [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for more information, I am sure that is more clear than your course that you are following.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all so much for all the helpful advice, especially the Browser Dev Tools console tip.

So, I changed the `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)` line to `Console(ex.Message)`, and the error I saw in the Browser Dev Tools console was:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44340/api/employee' from origin 'https://localhost:44362' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

I went to the `ConfigureServices()` method in the startup.cs file of the web service, and I changed the code from

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());
            });
```

to

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            });
```

The error is gone, and the employee record gets saved correctly now. I do realize that this isn't exactly a sound programming practice to call something like `AllowAnyMethod()`, but for the purposes of this course, it's sufficient for now. Thank you all again!